# Teamforge actions

Tags: c#, teamforge

I wanted to know if is it possible, using a c# application, to keep track of the different actions made by the users on our projects, documents and so on.
The purpose is to determine the number of open documents, open trackers, open file releases and so on. And of course the number of visits to the various projects.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar at my work place. TeamForge provides APIs for the customers to use. You can create your own custom application by using those APIs. They also provide documentation of how to use the APIs.

Comment: I've already used those APIs to extract lists of projects, documents and trackers. But I couldnt find the adequate function to get recent actions done by the users.

Comment: I've read that the data in the reports generated by Teamforge come from a special database that extracts live site data from the production database. I just wanted to know if we can or not access this data directly using a c# application.

Comment: The only way you can access anything of teamforge is through the APIs. Unfortunately, we have replaced TeamForge with Rally software which is more Agile so I can't help you any further. But I would suggest you try the TeamForge customer support.

Comment: They didn't answer :(. It's so urgent, and im consuming lot of time trying to do it.

Comment: Isn't there any kind of history table for users? Have you read the full documentation?